# Worksheet.Name causes OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in, out-of-memory

## .Net4 C# VSTO4 Excel Add-In:

The following function is called very often, let's say every second:

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Gets a unique identifier string of for  the worksheet in the format [WorkbookName]WorksheetName
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="workbook">The workbook.</param>
    /// <param name="worksheet">The worksheet.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A unique worksheet identifier string, or an empty string.
    /// </returns>
    public static string GetWorksheetUniqueIdentifier(Workbook workbook, dynamic worksheet)
    {
        if (workbook == null) return string.Empty;
        if (worksheet == null) return string.Empty;//Note: Worksheet can also be a diagram!

        return string.Format("[{0}]{1}", workbook.Name, worksheet.Name);
    }
```

**After a while, I am getting the following exception:**

```
System.OutOfMemoryException
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Resize()
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.SYMTBL.InsertChildNoGrow(Symbol child)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.SymFactoryBase.newBasicSym(SYMKIND kind, Name name, ParentSymbol parent)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.SymFactory.CreateLocalVar(Name name, ParentSymbol parent, CType type)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.PopulateLocalScope(DynamicMetaObjectBinder payload, Scope pScope, ArgumentObject[] arguments, IEnumerable`1 parameterExpressions, Dictionary`2 dictionary)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.BindCore(DynamicMetaObjectBinder payload, IEnumerable`1 parameters, DynamicMetaObject[] args, DynamicMetaObject& deferredBinding)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.Bind(DynamicMetaObjectBinder payload, IEnumerable`1 parameters, DynamicMetaObject[] args, DynamicMetaObject& deferredBinding)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.BinderHelper.Bind(DynamicMetaObjectBinder action, RuntimeBinder binder, IEnumerable`1 args, IEnumerable`1 arginfos, DynamicMetaObject onBindingError)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpInvokeMemberBinder.FallbackInvokeMember(DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject[] args, DynamicMetaObject errorSuggestion)
   at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject.BindInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject[] args)
   at System.Dynamic.InvokeMemberBinder.Bind(DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject[] args)
   at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObjectBinder.Bind(Object[] args, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, LabelTarget returnLabel)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder.BindCore[T](CallSite`1 site, Object[] args)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object )
   at TestAddIn.ExcelAccessor.GetWorksheetUniqueIdentifier(Workbook workbook, Object worksheet)
   at TestAddIn.ExcelAccessor.GetCurrentWorksheetUniqueIdentifier()
   at TestAddIn.ExcelAccessor.timerExcelObserver_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Calling code is:

```
  private static Timer timerExcelObserver = new Timer();

...

  timerExcelObserver.Tick += new EventHandler(this.timerExcelObserver_Tick);
  timerExcelObserver.Interval = 1000;
  timerExcelObserver.Start();

...

  private void timerExcelObserver_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  { 
    ...
    var updatedWorksheetIdentifierString = GetCurrentWorksheetUniqueIdentifier();
    ...
  }

  public static string GetCurrentWorksheetUniqueIdentifier()
  {
      return GetWorksheetUniqueIdentifier(ExcelApplication.ActiveWorkbook, ExcelApplication.ActiveSheet);
  }
```

---

**I have no idea why I am getting an exception!**

Can it maybe help to take a "using" in GetWorksheetUniqueIdentifier?

```
using(worksheet)
{
   return string.Format("[{0}]{1}", workbook.Name, worksheet.Name);
}
```

Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: looks as if something going wrong when inserting in some dictionary, can you share complete stacktrace

Comment: Where is this code being called from or how is it being used? It does not appear to be the direct cause of the problem (which is dying inside a Dictionary resize method), so the calling code may have the problem.

Comment: Don't dispose the `worksheet` object, which is what would happen if you use the `using` statement you posted. It is likely that the caller still needs to reference `worksheet` after your method finishes.

Comment: @Keith:I don't think the worksheet object is being disposed when leaving the using() clause, because there are some other references to it outside the function.

Comment: @HiTech Magic: The calling code is a timer, that is called every second. The worksheet-object is the Excels Application.ActiveWorksheet object.

Comment: @BrijeshMishra: Edited stacktrace => See above

Comment: The problem is the "dynamic" parameter and its runtime evaluation. Is this a bug in the implementatin of dynamic?

Comment: The calling code may be run via *a timer*, but what are the actual lines that are calling `GetWorksheetUniqueIdentifier`?

Comment: @HiTechMagic: I have added the calling code.

Comment: Why are you using `dynamic` rather than `Excel.Worksheet`?

Comment: @DanM: Because I have to. 
The Application.ActiveSheet is dynamic, that means it can be an instance of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet or Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Chart. Each of them supports the required "Name"-Property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try releasing the COM objects explicitly:

```
public static string GetCurrentWorksheetUniqueIdentifier()
{
    var workbook = ExcelApplication.ActiveWorkbook;
    var worksheet = ExcelApplication.ActiveSheet;

    try
    {
        return GetWorksheetUniqueIdentifier(workbook, worksheet);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (workbook != null &&
            Marshal.IsComObject(workbook))
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);

        if (worksheet != null && 
            Marshal.IsComObject(worksheet))
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
    }
}
```

This has been known to fix memory issues in some Office-related scenarios.

Comment: **I don't know if this really fixes the problem, because I can't reproduce it. But it is the best answer so far.**